# Compare column's value with other column and base on condition choose value from third column sql

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am new to SQL (Athena), I have a case where I want to compare predicted values column with original values column. It will compare with every value and take the id and revenue of greatest (comparing by it self). it's bit tricky I wil try to explain,Here for 16206.50  the greatest is 17852.21 so it will take 4 as id, for 21206.50 greatest is 40000 so it will take id 7, for 50365 since 40000 is greatest iso it will take that, for 18563 greatest is 20542 ao it will take 1 as id

Sample data

```
original      id     revenue       predicted
---------------------------------------------
13106.21      3      20000           16206.50 
17852.21      4      30000           21206.50 
20542         1      70000           50365
40000         7      80000           18563
```

Desired output is

```
original       id     revenue   predicted  pred_id    pred_revenue
-------------------------------------------------------------------
13106.21      3     20000      16206.50    4            300000
17852.21      4     30000      21206.50    7            80000
20542         1     70000      50365       7            80000
40000         7     80000       18563      1            70000
```

I am trying

```
SELECT
    original, id, revenue, predicted
FROM   
    (SELECT 
         *,
         MAX(original) OVER () AS max_original
     FROM   
         test)
WHERE 
    original >= predicted
```

but it is not returning the desired result and output.

Can someone please guide me - what is wrong or how to do it?

Comment: How do you have ids 3 and 7 in desired output while there is no such ids in the sample data?

Comment: @GuruStron it was typo mistake. I  fixed it

Comment: TBH still not clear what is the logic here. Can you please explain it in more steps?

Comment: @GuruStron I tried to explain in the question

Comment: _"for 50365 since 40000 is greatest iso it will take that"_ - does not sound right TBH =)

Comment: Do you need first value which is bigger then current one?

Comment: @ yesGuru Stron... you got it.

Comment: since 40000 is greatest of all existing values so we will take it's id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a left self join followed by grouping and fixing nulls with some window functions:

```sql
WITH dataset(original, id, revenue, predicted) AS (
values (13106.21,      3,      20000,           16206.50),
    (17852.21,      4,      30000,           21206.50),
    (20542   ,      1,      70000,           50365),
    (40000   ,      7,      80000,           18563)
)

select id, original, revenue, predicted,
  coalesce(pred_id, max_by(id, original) over () ) pred_id,
  coalesce(pred_revenue, max(original) over () ) pred_revenue
from (
    select l.id,
       arbitrary(l.original) original,
       arbitrary(l.revenue) revenue,
       arbitrary(l.predicted) predicted,
       min(r.original) pred_revenue,
       min_by(r.id, r.original) pred_id
    from dataset l
    left join dataset r on r.original > l.predicted
    group by l.id);
```

Output:

| id | original | revenue | predicted | pred_id | pred_revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 17852.21 | 30000 | 21206.50 | 7 | 40000.00 |
| 1 | 20542.00 | 70000 | 50365.00 | 7 | 40000.00 |
| 3 | 13106.21 | 20000 | 16206.50 | 4 | 17852.21 |
| 7 | 40000.00 | 80000 | 18563.00 | 1 | 20542.00 |

Comment: I am gonna accept your ans but I need revenue in Pred_revenue column not original.   if I  change min(r.original) pred_revenue to  min(r.revenue) pred_revenue. it works but if predicted is greater than 40000.00 than it always copy original and not revenue

Comment: @user19 use `max_by` for revenue, as done with `id`. Can't fix the query ATM. maybe later.

Comment: I want to use this query as intermediate query and then join with the main query. but If I tried to give it a name and used later sql throw error that only one select statement is allowed. is it because of nested query?

Comment: @user19 without the query it is hard to say

Comment: there is a query above which is calculating revenue and predicted value  let say `with dataset as (   formulas for calculations  ),  questioned_query as (  query which you wrote  ) select * from data set  d join questioned_query q on q.id=d.id `

Comment: @user19 it seems that error is somewhere in the subqueries, possibly you forgot to remove `;` from `query which you wrote`